# Which set to use for confirmatory data analysis

Tags: exploratory-data-analysis

I am exploring `data analysis` and want to perform confirmatory data analysis `CDA` on a dataset which I have splitted into `train set, dev set and test set`. I am new to CDA, As we normally perform Exploratory data analysis `EDA` on `train set`, so which set (train set or dev set) do we use to perform CDA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are strictly testing a (set of) hypotheses and not doing anything else, then you don't need to divide your data into train, test, etc. and can use the whole data set to test those.

BUT that means no model building, no looking at results and then doing something new, or anything like that. Set your hypothesis and test it (or them). If you are really doing that, there is no "training" to do.

Often, though, we are sort of in-between EDA and CDA. And some people do EDA on the whole set, as well, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks. My end goal is to build classification model, I am using `titanic` dataset. As a ML workflow or steps I am performing `EDA` on `train set` and also come to know about `CDA` so wanted to know on which set(train or dev set) do we use. From your answer, I think it is ok to do `CDA` on `train set`. But during search for `CDA` I was getting links for confirmatory factor analysis `CFA` which I think uses different set(other than Exploratory factor analysis EFA used). Does `CDA` and `CFA` are same thing? This `CFA` made me to think which set I should use for `CDA`.

Comment: "Confirmatory data analysis" is not the most common term, although it does make sense.  

For CDA, as I said, you can use the whole data set. 

But "building a classification model" is NOT likely to be a confirmatory task. It's sort of inherently exploratory. 

Also, when doing EDA and dividing into train, test, and (maybe) validation sets, what you are doing is EDA on train and then CDA on the validation set. 

Also, the Titanic data set has been so thoroughly explored that .... well, if you are just doing it to work on your skills, fine.

Comment: And CFA is one type of CDA. It is where you have a strong notion of how the factor analysis should look (from theory, or previous work, or whatever) and want to confirm that, maybe on a new data set or something like that. 

Finally (for now!) I'm a little worried by your saying "I heard about this and wanted to try it".  That's not a good way to do data analysis. First figure out what you want to find out, then how to do it.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks. You have mentioned `CDA` on `validation set` (I thought it is train set). Correct me if I understood wrong, if end goal is to build model then we can skip `CDA` and just perform `EDA` on `train set`. I am trying to implement ML lifecycle and during exploring data analysis as one of the step in ML lifecycle, I found `IDA -> EDA -> CDA`, so trying to learn `CDA`, Also while doing `EDA` and finding insights from it, do I need to perform `CDA` to confirm them?

Comment: Doing CDA on the train set makes no sense. Either a) You already have something that you want to confirm, in which case you do CDA on the whole data set (no splitting) or yu use EDA (on train set) to develop ideas and then do CDA on test (or maybe validation) to confirm it.

Also "trying to learn CDA" doesn't really make sense. Learn data analysis. If you've learned EDA then there is very little to learn for CDA.

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules on how to do this, you decide based on your experience/knowledge/goals. It might be the case that you know nothing about your data and hence cannot come up with any hypotheses to test, in which case you might just do EDA and report the results as tables/graphs with no concrete tests. It might be that you already have concrete hypotheses in mind which you want to test so you can skip all that EDA stuff and go straight to CDA and report your test results. Or it might be anything in between.

The whole train/(validation/)test split stuff is much more prevalent in machine learning rather than statistics, where the goal is often prediction. Usually in statistics you do not have that much data to be able to afford splitting your data, so you are stuck with just the one data set. And you decide (beforehand) what kind of analysis you will do, depending on your domain knowledge/expertise. If, however, you have loads of data (or enough data to have any meaningful power) you may split it into multiple parts and perform different analyses on each part, say EDA on one and CDA on another. As long as you make it clear what you've done, how, and why.